# Debug assertion Failed Opencv Function

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with my code. I try to execute a background substraction with opencv 3.0 on Visual Studio 2015. The function main is:

```
int main()
{

//altrimento creo la finestra
    Mat image;
    Mat fgMaskMOG2;
    Rect mr;
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pKNN;
    //imposto la sequenza delle immagini
    std::string path = "D:\\ProjectFile\\CoreSaw_DataFusion\\Dataset\\Persona posa oggetto\\gray-%06d.jpg";
    VideoCapture sequence(path);

    //se non è aperto esco con codice di errore
    if (!sequence.isOpened())
    {
        cerr << "Failed to open Image Sequence!\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (;;)
    {
        //scelgo l'immagine seguente
        sequence >> image;
        resize(image, image, Size(400,400));
        //ridimensiono l'immagine perchè permette una miglior rilevazione
        //se vuota finisco la sequenza
        if (image.empty())
        {
            cout << "End of Sequence" << endl;
            break;
        }
        try
        {
            apply_BackgroundSubstraction(image, fgMaskMOG2);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            cerr << "Main: " << exc.msg << endl;
        }
        waitKey(1); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my function is:

```
void apply_BackgroundSubstraction(Mat image, Mat fgMask)
{

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    try
    {
        namedWindow("Display window");// Create a window for display.
        Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pKNN = createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(216, 3500.0, true);
        pKNN->apply(image, fgMask); //applico l'algoritmo di background substraction 
        Mat contourImg = fgMask.clone();
        findContours(contourImg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        vector<vector< Point> >::iterator itc = contours.begin();
        while (itc != contours.end()) {

            Rect rect = boundingRect(Mat(*itc));
            rectangle(image, rect, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
            itc++;
        }
        imshow("Display window", fgMask);
        imshow("Blob", image);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        cerr << "apply_BackgroundSubstraction: " << exc.msg << endl;
    }
}
```

when this function ended i have this error

[DEBUG ASSERTION FAILDED : IS BLOCK_TYPE_VALID(HEADER->BLOCK_USE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDzHs.png)

can you help me?

Comment: Was opencv built using Visual Studio 14 2015?

Comment: yes, i use cmake with visual studio 14 2015

Answer (score 0):

it is not an answer to the error but you should create `createBackgroundSubtractorKNN` in your `main` function and pass it to your `apply_BackgroundSubstraction` function.

my test code is compiled with VS 2015 and working well.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void apply_BackgroundSubstraction( Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pKNN, Mat image, Mat fgMask)
{

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    try
    {
        namedWindow("Display window");// Create a window for display.
        pKNN->apply(image, fgMask); //applico l'algoritmo di background substraction
        Mat contourImg = fgMask.clone();
        findContours(contourImg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        vector<vector< Point> >::iterator itc = contours.begin();
        while (itc != contours.end()) {

            Rect rect = boundingRect(Mat(*itc));
            rectangle(image, rect, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
            itc++;
        }
        imshow("Display window", fgMask);
        imshow("Blob", image);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        cout << "apply_BackgroundSubstraction: " << exc.msg << endl;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"768x576.avi";
    VideoCapture capture( filename );

    Mat frame,output;
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pKNN = createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(216, 3500.0, true);

    while(true)
    {
        capture.read(frame);
        if (!frame.data)
            return 0;

        apply_BackgroundSubstraction( pKNN, frame, output);

        if(waitKey(1)==27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks i try but i have the same error :( the problem is when the function apply_BackgroundSubstraction ended! :(

Comment: i think you have a problem about your VS configuration.